# How to use Kendo UI/Mobile with Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to decide what tech to use to create a mobile app. I want to be able to share as much code as possible between web, iOS & Android. To do this I'm planning on using HTML & javascript, then wrapping the apps using PhoneGap.

I've tried using AngularJS several times, but it's too complicated for me to learn (I want to get the app out, not spend months learning the framework). I've been watching tutorials on ember.js and it looks like it has a much more familiar architecture for me.

I like the look of Kendo UI core & mobile, but can't find any examples of using the widgets from an ember app. Is it possible to do that, or would it likely be so painful or would I have to write so much glue code that I'd wish I hadn't bothered? If so, is there a better way I can get a decent set of cross-platform widgets?

Comment: You can and probably will also spend months learning Ember. There is no meaningful difference in complexity compared with Angular IMHO. Mixing frameworks/view architectures is probably also a bad idea.

Comment: I would prefer kendoUI, since it has EVERYTHING I need, and a lot of rooms to work with.
Its SPA feature is (i must say) simple, but, it's easy to build your custom logic on top.